# NSTableView vertical grid colors on Lion

Tags: osx-lion, nstableview

My app includes an NSTableView setup from NIB. In the NIB file I've added Solid Vertical Grid then compiled it under OS X 10.8 but with deployment target OS X 10.7. Everything works fine on OS X 10.8, but on 10.7 the vertical lines only appear in rows that doesn't contain any data.

Do you have any clues why this happens?

---

Edit
[image]

As you can see, there is one line where no data appears and the vertical grid lines are there.

Comment: just to make things clear, would it be possible to add screenshots?

Comment: just some minutes and I can add screenshots

Comment: I am also facing the same problem,Did u find any solution

Comment: No, I didn't, but after a while I had to support OS X 10.6 too, so I've recreated the tableview from code. But the problem is still interesting to me.